# If $\sum_{n}\frac{\sigma_{n}^{2}}{n^{2}}=\infty$, then $\sigma_{n}^{2}\geq n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $\sum_{n}\frac{\sigma_{n}^{2}}{n^{2}}=\infty$ and $\sigma_{n}^{2}\geq 0$, then can we assume wlog that $\sigma_{n}^{2}\geq n$?

To show this one idea is to construct $s_{n}<1$ s.t. $\sigma_{n}^{2}\leq n^{s_{n}}$ and so $\sum_{n}\frac{\sigma_{n}^{2}}{n^{2}}\leq \sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{2-s_{n}}}<\infty$.

Comment: Take $\sigma^2_n = n-1$

Comment: There are series with smaller terms than $\frac{1}{n}$ that diverge.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\sigma_{n}^{2}=\Omega(n)$? i.e. $\sigma_{n}^{2}\geq cn$ for some constant $c$ (in principle very small).  Otherwise, take $\sigma_{n}^{2}=\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Also try $c_n^2 = n/\log n$.

Comment: But even if you mean $\sigma_n^2 \sim n $, this is false.  Consider $\sigma_n^2 = n/\ln n $.